# Why the edges displayed in render

Tags: rendering

As shown in the picture, why the square in the red circle looks lighter? I can see the edges in the middle. The normal is correct in edit mode. The shading smooth is is clicked. It looks good in materials. [image][image]
[image]

Comment: Probably - inconsistent normals (Ctrl+N with all selected), double vertices, wrongly created (baked with intersecting islands etc) or set up normal map (if in Cycles Image Texture has to be set to Non-Color data). Other than that hard to guess

Comment: You're showing us face normals.. have you had a look at vertex normals?

Comment: If you upload a .blend, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Select the object in object mode and turn on smooth shading for the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on. The materials are imported with the models.... This model is combined from two models. It looks strange in texture view, though I modified the texture... 
Finally, I delete the materials and recreate it. Everything is somehow good now, except for texture view...

Comment: is this an answer?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why in the texture view. The model have multiple textures though I recreate a new material.... @cegaton